# How to assign values to a list of variables in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, variables

If I write this code:

```
lst = [one, two, three] = [i for i in range(1,4)]
```

I can access the first elemnt of the list by `lst[0]` and by `one` at will.

How can I assign the values in the later for loop with the same result?
A for loop I am referring to, e.g.:

```
for count, i in enumerate(range(1,4)):
    lst[count] = i
```

Of course, I can't start even from that:

```
lst = [one, two, three]
```

I am stuck and don't know how to properly do this.

I can do a workaround using dictionary but that's not what I want.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Sounds like the [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) issue. A dictionary is the way.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb as I said, I want to access a value `"one"` by calling either `one`, or `lst[0]`.

Comment: @ForceBru, a good read, thank you for a hint. Probably, the dictionary is the only way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @Nick not actually, since they use dict, and this is not what I wanted.